# How to set a permanent time and date on Raspberry Pi?

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi

I am using the Debian flavor of Linux on Raspberry Pi, and I want to set the date and time permanently. I am using the following command.

```
sudo date -s "Mar  08:10"
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change date & time in `/etc/fake-hwclock.data`. This helped me, 
it was found [there](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=17175).

But there is still a chance of me misunderstanding the question. It would help if you want to set default date & time.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that by "set permanent time" you mean you want to set the date (at most) once and then have it power up with the correct time. I have three suggestions.

Option 1 - The Raspberry Pi does not have a clock, but one could be added.  See [this question in the Raspberry Pi Forum](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1544) and [this aftermarket hardware clock](http://learn.adafruit.com/adding-a-real-time-clock-to-raspberry-pi/overview).  I'm sure there are other hardware clocks available.

Option 2 - Use some sort of network connection and get the time via [NTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol), but I expect that is not what you were looking for.

Option 3 - Use a GPS chip and collect the time from that. If you get one with NMEA output to a serial port (available from the vendor in the above link and others) you don't need any special software. See [this description of NMEA sentences](http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm#RMC) for help in extracting the date from the GPS output. This will not work very well if the device is not able to get a GPS fix.